# flixel hello world not working

Tags: apache-flex

This is the code that i compiled using mxmlc the free flex sdk. It compiled and i ran it. Helloworld not displayed

```
 package
    {
        import org.flixel.*;

        public class PlayState extends FlxState
        {
            override public function create():void
            {
                add(new FlxText(0,0,100,"Hello, World!")); //adds a 100x20 text field at position 0,0 (upper left)
            }
        }   

    }
```

Expected output is = HelloWorld. But is not displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to provide an FlxGame subclass too. It may be easiest for you to take an existing Flixel project that works out of the box such as [AdamAtomic's HelloWorld](https://github.com/AdamAtomic/HelloWorld) and modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: why is a FlxGame subclass is needed ? Can you please explain this to me. Iam completely new. :(

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around.  [HelloWorld.as](https://github.com/AdamAtomic/HelloWorld/blob/master/src/HelloWorld.as) (in that example you game) is the main class which extends FlxGame.  That create the game engine construct, but then needs instructions as to what to load (which game?), this is where PlayState comes in and sets a game state.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
package  
{   
import org.flixel.*;    

    public class HelloWorld extends FlxState
    {

        private var title_text:FlxText;     

        public function HelloWorld() { }        

        override public function create():void
        {           
            title_text = new FlxText(20, 0, 300, 'Lunarium');
            title_text.setFormat(null, 50, 0xffffffff, "center");
            add(title_text);                
        }

        override public function update():void
        {
            if(FlxG.keys.X)
            {
                FlxG.fade(0xff131c1b, 1, onFade);   
            }           
            super.update();          
        }       

        protected function onFade():void
        {       
            //FlxG.switchState(new SmallPlay2());
        }
    }   
}
```

There are plenty of tool tips to help you figure out what the different settings mean. I found flixel rather easy to use coming from a Multimedia Fusion 2 background.

Enjoy!